# Same Mathematica 9.1 Student License on both Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: front-end, licensing

Is it possible to install Mathematica 9.1 on both Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and Windows 7 Home Premium on the same machine. I want to be able to use Mathematica on Ubuntu since I wrote some numerical codes there. I would like to know if this is possible and a GUI is present in UNIX operating systems.

Thanks

Comment: Inquiries about licensing are off topic here, but [Wolfram support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) will be happy to help you with such questions.  Please understand that this is not an official Wolfram site.  We are users like you and not in a position to answer such questions.

Comment: @Szabolc I knew, but I thought maybe someone might have tried these sort of things.

Comment: @szabolcs I know you proposed [here in meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164/57) that license questions would be off-topic, but it's currently not in our site FAQ. Besides, I have the feeling that many of those questions may be answerable, as chances are one of our thousands of users will have been dealing with something very similar, as demonstrated by the answer below.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I doubt that the answer below is correct at all.  There are many different situations and different (student) licenses and the OP didn't even explain clearly what kind of license he has.  The majority of people won't have experience with various types of licenses, so they can't answer questions like this with an answer that's dependable and useful for others in the future. Also, licensing changes more quickly than the software itself. I think that the (likely wrong) answer below just proves that this type of question should be off topic.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries   Besides, support is so easy to contact: they even have live chat support for issues like this (not for technical issue).  The OP would have gotten a quicker and reliable answer if he just calls them or if he uses the live chat support.

Comment: @Sjoerd I imagine that if the OP gets his license from his school then he can just get another activation code and install it on another machine/OS.  But some personal student licenses probably allow installation only on a single machine.  I didn't want to discuss it though because I'm not sure, and also because "licensing" is really just an agreement between the user and the company and might change if the OP contacts WRI and explain his situation.  It's not a fixed objective thing like the correct syntax of `Table` that's guaranteed not to change until the next release.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good points. Perhaps we should be working on getting this restriction in the FAQ.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries This line is now in the FAQ: "Questions on licensing, specific support arrangements, product availability and pre-release versions of Mathematica — please contact Wolfram Support at support@wolfram.com"

Comment: @rm-rf Well done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is possible without any trouble. I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 with Mathematica installed on both under a student licence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have the same setup and would like to do the same thing. By the way do you know if the license is somehow bounded to the machine such that if you change a hardware component or install it on a different computer it won't work.

Comment: I'd say this shouldn't be a problem. Not sure though.

Comment: @Vesnog The license is usually bound to the $MachineID. This means moving it to a different PC won't work without talking to Wolfram, Inc.