# Can one license be used on a dual-boot machine?

Tags: windows, linux, installation, licensing

I am considering buying a new machine with two hard disks, and my plan is to have it dual boot, with Windows 10 in one disk, and Ubuntu in the other. If I buy a single license for Mathematica, can I use the same details on both the Windows and Linux installations (since I believe the MathID is unique to a computer anyway)? I wanted to ask before investing in the two disk machine; if this is not possible, I'll just get a single machine and choose between the two. But it would be nice if this was possible.

Comment: This was asked before [same-mathematica-9-1-student-license-on-both-ubuntu-and-windows-7](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46104/same-mathematica-9-1-student-license-on-both-ubuntu-and-windows-7)